# pandas pivot table without grouping index

Tags: python, pandas

What if you want to do a pivot table without returning the index as a multiindex?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                   'B': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female'], 
                   'C': ['1-5', '6-10', '1-5', '6-10', '1-5', '6-10', '1-5', '6-10']})
```

If you use `pivot_table` (also margins=True here will cause errors):

```
df.pivot_table(index=['A','B'],
               columns='C',
               aggfunc='size',
               fill_value=0)
```

This will return:

```
  C         1-5  6-10
A B                
A Female    1     0
  Male      2     0
B Female    1     2
  Male      0     2
```

But I am looking for the this output:

```
            var_name         
C           1-5 6-10 All
value                   
A             3    0   3
B             1    4   5
Female        2    2   4
Male          2    2   4
All           8    8  16
```

There surely must be an easier way with either `pivot_table`, `pivot` or `crosstab` than doing a melt and then a `pivot_table` as below:

```
(df.melt(id_vars=['C'],value_vars=['A','B'],var_name='var_name').pivot_table(index=['value'], 
                                                                                         columns=['type'],
                                                                                         aggfunc='count',
                                                                                         fill_value=0,
                                                                                         margins=True))
```

Comment: where is `type` in your shared data?

Comment: hmmm, I think `melt` + `pivot_table` is one of simpliest solutions, I think `easier` (if think one function) solution not possible in pandas

Comment: @sammywemmy sry bout that, updated.

Comment: @jezrael so there's no way to not have stacked indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One similar idea with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) is similar like your solution:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['C'],value_vars=['A','B'],var_name='var_name')
df = pd.crosstab(df['value'], df['C'] ,margins=True)
print (df)
C       1-5  6-10  All
value                 
A         3     0    3
B         1     4    5
Female    2     2    4
Male      2     2    4
All       8     8   16
```

I think one function in pandas not exist, because need first unpivot by `melt` and then `pivot`.

Comment: looks nicer to be honest. don't you ever feel you'd like to do what I want to do with easier syntax than melt + crosstab/pivot?